Download, unzip and read CSV file from GCS Bucket with Node
I try to read a csv File from a Google Cloud Storage Bucket with Node (Google Cloud Functions).
The CSV File is zipped like this:

    const {google} = require('googleapis');
    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const {parse} = require("csv-parse");

    const storage = new Storage({
      projectId: 'XXX',
      keyFilename: './api-project-XXX.json'
    });


    const file = storage.bucket('pubsite_prod_rev_XXX').file("sales/salesreport_202406.zip");

    const content = await file.download({destination: "/tmp/test"}, function(err, file) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("download successful");
      }
    });

How could I unzip and read the CSV File? Should createReadStream be used here? Does the file have to be saved in a bucket first or can it be unzipped directly?

This Link1 seems a perfect solution for your requirement. Can you cross check once? Also have a look at this Link2 and Link3.

@SandeepVokkareni thanks, I solved it with createReadStream and pipe

My solution is:
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const csv = require('csv-parser');

...

 const file = "sales/salesreport_XXX.zip";
    const results = [];

    await storage
      .bucket('pubsite_prod_rev_XXX')
      .file(file)
      .createReadStream() // stream is created
      .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
      .on('entry', (entry) => {
        console.log('path', entry.path);

        entry
          .pipe(csv({separator: ','}))
          .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
          .on('end', () => {
            console.log(results);
          })
          .on('error', function() {
            console.log("Error parsing CSV data");
          });
      })
      .on('finish', () => {
        // The file download is complete
        console.log("stream successful");
      });

